# How i can list all the entities inside a CSV file which does not exists inside an SQL table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table named Stations, with these values:-

1. ID
2. Name

and i have a `.CSV` file which contain stations' names, so my question is how i can list all the `.CSV` entities which exist inside the `.CSV` file but not inside the database table?

Thanks

Comment: Load them into a temporary table and do a `LEFT JOINS` on `NAME`

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2019 you could use *polybase* to join your csv and table directly.

Answer (score 0):

Select *
from stations
where stations.name
NOT IN (put the data from the CSV File here separated by commas)

This will show you all the data in the table where which is not in the CSV file.